# inserting yes or no values based on fields in different tables being equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I have a field created titled LeadInventor,

what I want SQL Server to do is insert yes into the LeadInventor field if the names from the first inventor table match the inventor table.  The first inventor table has the names as one field, the inventor table has them separated first and last

this is the coding I have so far, which I know is wrong.

```
if inventor.InventorFirst + ' ' +inventor.InventorLast  = firstinventor.firstinventorname
insert into Inventor(LeadInventor) values ('Yes')
else insert into Inventor(leadinventor) values ('No');
```

What I would like to know is how do I fix it, or re-write it so that it will do what I ask it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE i
SET LeadInventor = 
    CASE 
        WHEN fi.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
    END
FROM Inventor i
    LEFT JOIN FirstInventor fi
    ON i.InventorFirst + ' ' + i.InventorLast = fi.FirstInventorName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think inner join with case would do, as you are matching the string

UPDATE inv
SET LeadInventor =
    CASE 
        WHEN fi.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No' 
        WHEN fi.FirstInventorName ='' THEN 'No'  --assuming you want NO even for blankfirst name, if not remove this line
       ELSE 'Yes'
    END
FROM Inventor inv
    INNER JOIN FirstInventor firstinv
    ON  firstinv.FirstInventorName = inv.InventorFirst + ' ' + inv.InventorLast

Comment: This would work to, but I did need both fields to be blank now just one of the names.  Sometimes the way some of this data is stored just makes no sense at all, I could have a record with no first name, but like 3 separate names in the last name box.

I think anyone who does any form of data entry should be required to at least understand the principles of DB's and how fields work,

Comment: yes, form UI should have strict validations, because without first name registration  and other data does not make any sense.

Comment: unfortunately this data doesnt come from a form, it comes from xml files... I believe the main program is the guy who wrote the extraction platform in python just wanted to get the data out, without doing it in a meaningful, and Its easier to fix it in SQL then it would be for me to learn python