# returning a yes or no value based on 2 matching fields

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update

I had a [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571773/inserting-yes-or-no-values-based-on-fields-in-different-tables-being-equal/11572363?noredirect=1#comment15325935_11572363) about setting a value to yes or no based on fields from 2 table matching.  I am trying to have the query check the generalsource.firstinventor and if it matches inventor.inventorfull insert "Yes" or else insert "No"
The result was the following code:

```
UPDATE i
SET LeadInventor = 
    CASE 
        WHEN fi.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
    END
FROM Inventor i
    LEFT JOIN FirstInventor fi
    ON i.InventorFirst + ' ' + i.InventorLast = fi.FirstInventorName
```

Which worked fantastically, until I tried to put into MySQL and I can not figure out whats wrong with the syntax.  How do I fix it?

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Inventor i     LEFT JOIN FirstInventor fi     ON i.InventorFirst + ' ' + i.' at line 7
```

Comment: Error messsages usually give you a hint.  What did yours say?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Inventor i     LEFT JOIN FirstInventor fi     ON i.InventorFirst + ' ' + i.' at line 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CONCAT string as

```
CONCAT( i.InventorFirst, ' ', i.InventorLast )
```

**UPDATE:** Also, there seems to be syntactic problem in your update statement, it should be as follows

```
UPDATE 
  Inventor i
  LEFT JOIN FirstInventor fi ON CONCAT( i.InventorFirst, ' ', i.InventorLast ) = fi.FirstInventorName
SET LeadInventor = 
    CASE 
        WHEN fi.FirstInventorName IS NULL THEN 'No' 
        ELSE 'Yes' 
    END
```

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: @JohnnyB Sorry, not sure how I missed the rest of the syntax, please try now, I have updated the answer

Comment: `Error Code: 1146. Table 'sharppatentdb.firstinventor' doesn't exist`  There is something wrong with my naming conventions but I dont know what.  one table is generalsource  the other table is inventor

Comment: The query given by you uses the table names as firstinventor & Inventor. you can try changing the table names